# Label in caption

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

For certain styles it appears that the `\label` statement must be included in `\caption` to preserve good referencing. Why is that?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: For instance JSS template: http://www.jstatsoft.org/ .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, `\label` must appear after (not necessarily inside) `\caption`, because the `\caption` command increments the counter to which `\label`'s argument associates itself.

Comment: +1: exactly. Putting it inside the `\caption` additionally guarantees that it can't get lost.  I find myself putting `\label`s inside `\section` commands equally redundantly, for the same reason.

Answer (score 9):

`\caption` (re)defines a macro `\@currentlabel`, which `\label` then uses.

i've recently seen a post from someone who had written something like

```
{\itshape \caption{foo bar}}\label{foobar}
```

(anyone with any experience would baulk at that, but it has happened.)

then since `\@currentlabel` was defined inside a group, `\label` ended up
referring to the last `\caption` that *wasn't* inside a group, since the
value hadn't been exported from inside the group.

putting `\label` inside the caption solves the problem for *this* class of
misguided people, in a "robust" way.

for only ordinarily-misguided people, it's enough just to say "put the
\label immediately after the `\caption` (or whatever); don't have spaces
or line breaks in between"

the grouping effect applies equally well for sections and other things
that can be labelled.

Comment: The problem is that you must sometimes use a template that messes that up.

Comment: Thanks for the extra description of exactly how labeling works. +1.

Answer (score 0):

mbq claims that some templates mess the label system up.  if that's so, you just have not to use labels.

fwiw, i've downloaded and scanned the jss stuff that mbq mentioned, and see no
indication that label processing is anything other than standard.