# Function numbering in algorithms

Tags: algorithm2e, algpseudocode

Algorithms are getting numbered automatically but unable to get same for the functions.

In the following example, Algorithms are numbered as Algorithm 1 and Algorithm 2 by themselves but Functions didn't. Please advice.

```
\documentclass{ucbthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,shadows,patterns,intersections,calc,fit}
\usepackage{dashbox}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{First Algorithm}
    \For{$j \in V$}{
    }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Second Algorithm}
    \For{$j \in V$}{
    }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{function}        
    \label{function1}   
    \caption{First Function ()}     
    \For{$k \in R$}{

    }       
\end{function}  

\begin{function}    
    \label{function2}
    \caption{Second Function ()}    
    \For{$k \in R$}{    

    }       
\end{function}

I am refering to function \ref{function1} and function \ref{function2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is the package option `procnumbered`, which “makes the procedure and function to be numbered as algorithm”. See Page 19 of the [`algorithm2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) manual.

**Added**: In order to get the cross-reference right, you need to place `\label` *after* `\caption` as @egreg mentioned in the comments below. See also [this short explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33/164314) by @PhilMiller and [this longer explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6876/164314) by @anon.

```
\documentclass{ucbthesis}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,procnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{First Algorithm}
    \For{$j \in V$}{
    }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Second Algorithm}
    \For{$j \in V$}{
    }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{function}
    \caption{First Function ()}
    \label{function1}
    \For{$k \in R$}{
    }
\end{function}

\begin{function}
    \caption{Second Function ()}
    \label{function2}
    \For{$k \in R$}{
    }
\end{function}

I am refering to Function~\ref{function1} and Function~\ref{function2}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Functions numbered]

In case you want your functions to be numbered independently, then you need to set up a new counter for the `function` environment:

```
\documentclass{ucbthesis}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,procnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
% Set up a new counter for function
\newcounter{function}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Change the original counter to the new counter
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{function}{%
  \let\c@algocf\c@function
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{First Algorithm}
    \For{$j \in V$}{
    }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Second Algorithm}
    \For{$j \in V$}{
    }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{function}
    \caption{First Function ()}
    \label{function1}
    \For{$k \in R$}{
    }
\end{function}

\begin{function}
    \caption{Second Function ()}
    \label{function2}
    \For{$k \in R$}{
    }
\end{function}

I am refering to Function~\ref{function1} and Function~\ref{function2}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Functions numbered independently]

Please note that

- if you are using [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption), please consider using [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) (which is distributed with `caption`), instead of `subfig`.
- if you want to use Times-like fonts, consider replacing `mathptmx` with the more recent [`newtxtext` and `newtxmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx).

**Added**: Please use [non-breaking space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15547/164314) `~` between a label name and its number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked well but when I am using \ref in the text in order to create a link for the function. I am getting function 1 for all the \refs. However I should be getting function 1, function 2 and function 3.

Comment: @YogeshSharma `\label` should go *after* `\caption`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Please follow @egreg’s comment. I updated my answer to include a few explanations. Also, please use `~` between a label name and its number.