# LaTex: Table numbering begins at 2

Tags: tables, numbering, longtable

My table numbering is not working correctly. I have defined continuous numbers like this:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
```

which works fine, but for some reason the numbering starts at 2. Only if I place the table at the very start of my document, it begins at 1.
Look at this:

```
\begin{document}

% Deckblatt
\begin{spacing}{1}
    \input{ads/deckblatt}
\end{spacing}
\newpage

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Test\label{tab:table-test}}
\end{table}

...
\end{document}
```

It results in Table 2 on page 2 after the cover sheet:
[image]

However, if I move the table before the cover sheet, it becomes table 1 (in the center of the page):

[image]

So I thought the code in `\input{ads/deckblatt}` is causing this, however its content doesn't seem to make any changes to numberings:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{longtable}{p{.4\textwidth} p{.4\textwidth}}
      {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{images/logo.png}} & 
      {\includegraphics[height=2.6cm]{images/dhbw.png}}
    \end{longtable}
    \enlargethispage{20mm}
    \begin{center}
      \vspace*{12mm}    {\LARGE\bf \titel }\\
      \vspace*{12mm}    {\large\bf \arbeit}\\
      \vspace*{12mm}    für die Prüfung zum\\
      \vspace*{3mm}     {\bf \abschluss}\\
      \vspace*{12mm}    des \studiengang\\
      \vspace*{3mm}     an der Dualen Hochschule Baden-Württemberg \dhbw\\
      \vspace*{12mm}    von\\
      \vspace*{3mm}     {\large\bf \autor}\\
      \vspace*{12mm}    \datumAbgabe\\
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \begin{spacing}{1.2}
    \begin{tabbing}
        mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm     \= \kill
        \textbf{Bearbeitungszeitraum}  \>  \zeitraum\\
        \textbf{Matrikelnummer, Kurs}  \>  \martrikelnr, \kurs\\
        \textbf{Ausbildungsfirma}      \>  \firma, \firmenort\\
        \textbf{Betreuer}              \>  \betreuer\\
        \textbf{Gutachter}             \>  \gutachter
    \end{tabbing}
    \end{spacing}
\end{titlepage}
```

Why does the table numbering start at 2 and how can I prevent this from happening? In case thats relevant, I am using documentclass `scrreprt`.

Comment: Please provide a complete [MWE (with all preamble)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/119). It makes it much easier for other users to help you if you can provide code that they can copy and test on their own installations without having to guess at missing packages.

Comment: What's in the file `ads/deckblatt.tex`?

Comment: @Mico: that is the tittlepage, the final chunk of code shown in the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`longtable` implements its own captioning command, which allows the table number and caption be printed on every page. To make this work `longtable` increments the `table` counter.

(Try putting a table before and after the title page. You will probably see that the first table before is Table 1, and the table after is Table 3 [skipping 2 which is the longtable].)

---

Why are you using `longtable` anyways? The pair of logos shouldn't break across page boundaries. You can easily typeset the pair of logos without using *any* table environment.

**Edit**: In view of the fact that this is a provided template, the easiest workaround is to just `\setcounter{table}{0}` after you input your title page.

Comment: You're right. Putting one before and one after the title page results in table 2 missing.
I just use the template of my university, as I have never done anythinh in LaTeX before - that's why the longtable is there

Comment: Okay, in that case you can just force the counter to reset to zero after loading the title page. See edit.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: longtable incrementing the table counter is _such_ a bad idea, who can we blame for this design?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : would it make sense to introduce a * variant (like `align` versus `align*`) that doesn't touch the table counter and forces the caption to not show any numbering?